# Pass arguments to JQuery .on() fired by Element

Tags: jquery, triggers, arguments

Maybe anybody can help me.

```
<video>
</video>

[...]

$("video").on("loadstart", function() {
    console.log(a);
    // result: 'undefined'
});

$("video").on("loadeddata", function() {
    console.log(a);
    // result: 'undefined'
});

var a = 1;
$("video").attr("src", "myvideo.mp4");
$("video").trigger("load");
```

How do I get the variable 'a' used in .on() events that are not triggered by me?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to declared the variable at the global scope:

```
window.a = 1;
```

You can call the variable:

```
console.log(a)
```

Or:

```
console.log(window['a']);
```